# Efficient Parallelization of small outer loops and big inner loop in R

Tags: r

I have the following `R` code

```
LLL = list()
idx = 1
for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in 1:9){
     for(k in 1:13){
        for(iter in 1:1000000){
       
           if( runif(1,0,1)<0.5 ){
             LLL[[idx]] = rnorm(1,0,1)
             idx = idx + 1
          }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to parallelize efficiently this code?

What I was thinking is that I have `351` configurations of `i,j,k`, If I could distribute these configurations to cores and each core would run a  `for` loop for `1000000` iterations, can something similar to that be implemented??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of calling `rnorm()` one million times, it would be more efficient to call it once with the argument `n = 1000000`.
2. To utilize R's functional programming features we should try to avoid writing `for()`-loops. We can instead first create an object that represents your 351 configurations and then iterate on that object. See below for an example of how to do that.

Create configurations:

```
cfgs <-
  expand_grid(i = 1:3,
              j = 1:9,
              k = 1:13)
```

Code without parallelization.

```
cfgs |> 
  split(1:nrow(cfgs)) |> 
  lapply(\(x) rnorm(100000, 0, 1))
```

In order to parallelize the execution of the code we can use the `furrr` package.

```
library(furrr)
plan(multisession)
cfgs |> 
  split(1:nrow(cfgs)) |> 
  future_map(\(x) rnorm(100000, 0, 1), .options = furrr_options(seed=TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I just use ```rnorm```  for the illustration of the problem. It could be any other function that cannot wrap up the 1000000 iterations